# element()* にドキュメントオーダーを強制する

Tags: xml, xsl, xslt

以下は入力のXML文書から目次を作るために対象要素を変数（element()*）に格納したコードです．目次の対象は

- 用語集
- 索引
- 章とその下の2階層のtopicref（DITAの場合）、section（DocBookの場合）

を示しています．

［DITAのコード］

```
<xsl:variable name="tocCandidatesElem" as="element()*">
    <xsl:sequence select="$map/descendant::*[contains(@class,' bookmap/indexlist ')]"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="$map/descendant::*[contains(@class,' bookmap/glossarylist ')]"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$map/descendant::*[contains(@class,' bookmap/chapter ') or contains(@class,' bookmap/appendix ')]">
        <xsl:variable name="topicRef" as="element()" select="."/>
        <xsl:sequence select="$topicRef/descendant-or-self::*[position() le 3]"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

※ $mapはbookmapを指すものとお考えください．

［DocBookの場合］

```
<xsl:variable name="tocCandidatesElem" as="element()*">
    <xsl:sequence select="/set/book[1]/glossary"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="/set/book[1]/index"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="/set/book[1]/chapter | /set/book[1]/appendix">
        <xsl:variable name="chapter" as="element()" select="."/>
        <xsl:sequence select="$chapter/>
        <xsl:sequence select="$chapter/descendant::section[position() le 2]"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

※ DocBookは最近やっていないので怪しいかもしれません．

さて$tocCandidatesElemから実際に目次を作成したいのですが、このままでは索引、用語集、章、...の順となってしまい、文書の中に中に定義された順（ドキュメントオーダー）になっていません．

$tocCandidatesElemの中の定義順がどうあれ、ドキュメントオーダーになるような新しい変数を$tocCandidatesElemから作るにはどのようにしたらよいでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

挙げている例がややこしすぎる（よく見ると単なる XPath におけるドキュメント オーダーの話のようなのに、なぜ DITA や DocBook が出てくる必要があるのでしょうか…）上に、
簡潔なインプット、求めるアウトプット、簡潔な再現コードのセットも書かれていないので、
求めていることがすぐに分からないのですが、
`<xsl:variable as="element()*" name="foo" select="$tocCandidatesElem/." />` とか `<xsl:variable as="element()*" name="foo" select="$tocCandidatesElem | ()" />` とかを求めているのでしょうか？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます．質問のサンプルは実務で目次作成のコーディングしていた際のものをそのまま使用しました．また行いたいことは題にありますように「element()* にドキュメントオーダーを強制」したelement()*の新しい変数を作ることです．

Comment: 「ドキュメントオーダーを強制」というのが「ドキュメント オーダーでソート」という意味だとすれば、前記の `xsl:variable` でいけると思います。